# register view helper path in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2, view-helpers

I am migrating from Zend Framework 1.12 to 2.0. So far I have learned how to register individual custom view helpers. Is it also possible to register a path for (multiple) view helpers?

In ZF1 I accomplished this by putting the following in my application.ini:

```
resources.view.helperPath.Application_View_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers"
```

With the result that:

`$this->myHelper1` (and ...2, ...3, etc.)

would automatically load:

```
MyApp/module/Application/src/Application/View/Helper/MyHelper1.php
```

How can I achieve something similar in ZF2?

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register all of your custom helpers in your config like this:

```
'view_helpers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'myHelper1' => 'Application\View\Helper\MyHelper1',
        'myHelper2' => 'Application\View\Helper\MyHelper2',
    ),  
),
```

Because all helpers calls come from Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer magic method __call(), I think it is possible to register a path by extending original PhpRenderer and overwrite plugin() or __call() methods.

But register helpers by a path is not recommend. ZF2 is a Service based framework, everything including Helpers/Plugins/Controllers should be pre-established services which need to defined in config, it is good for performance and safety.

Comment: Thx but that is what I already know. I would prefer however to register just the path not the individual helpers. Do you have any idea if that is possible?

Comment: all helpers come from Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer magic method __call(), I think it is possible to register a path by extending original PhpRenderer and overwrite plugin() or __call() methods. But it is really not recommend. ZF2 is a Service based frameworks, everything including Helpers/Plugins/Controllers should be pre-established services which need to defined in config, it is good for performance and safety.

Comment: ok, that is an acceptable trade-off: inconvenience for performance and safety. If you include your comment in your answer I'll accept and upvote it.

Comment: Added comment to my answer